# How to set variable outside axios get

Tags: javascript, axios

I can't return a value using this function because it is empty.

```
getNameById (id) {

    var name = ''

    axios.get('/names/?ids=' + id)
      .then(response => {
        this.response = response.data
        name = this.response[0].name
      })
      .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
      })
    // Is empty
    console.log('Name ' + name)
    return name
  }
```

How do I access the name variable inside "then" and return it?

Comment: Yes it does not return

Answer (score 21):

You should return the *promise* instead.

```
getNameById (id) {
  return axios.get('/names/?ids=' + id)
      .then(response => {
        this.response = response.data
        return this.response[0].name
      })
  }
```

and use it:

```
getNameById(someId)
  .then(data => {
    // here you can access the data
  });
```

Comment: Correct approach (+1) from me ! @OP for further info please have a look here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then

Comment: Thanks @Christos!

Comment: You are welcome dude !

Comment: How do I access the content on the promise then?

Comment: personObject.name = this.getNameById(id) returns null

Comment: I am not sure how your response looks like, but it;;s in the `response` object. Can you give me a hint how it looks like ?

Comment: when I try to wrap my function in something like getNameByID I get: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{' "

Comment: It's work with me, thank you so much

Comment: I am also looking for below 
{ var somevar = getNameById(someId) }
I want access something from promise blocks and pass to some other function in my code