# Cannot set a global variable equal to a value returned from a Promise

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, react-native, promise, axios

I'm attempting to set a global variable equal to a JSON element being returned from a Promise with Axios, within my React Native application. I've followed the advice from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44231366/how-to-set-variable-outside-axios-get#), but still am unable to set the variable's value.

Here is my method using an Axios call:

```
  temp_high = null;

  _getForecast(zipcode)
  {
    const request = "http://api.wunderground.com/api/" + API_KEY + "/forecast/q/" + zipcode + ".json";
    return axios.get(request).then( (response) => {
        if(response.status == 200) {
            this.response = response.data;
            return this.response;
        }
    });
  }
```

And my render:

```
render() {
this._getForecast(49306).then(data => {
  this.temp_high = parseInt(data.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].high.fahrenheit);
});
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>Weather for Belmont, MI</Text>
    <Text>High: {this.temp_high}</Text>
    <Text></Text>
  </View>
  );
 }
}
```

If I log `data.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].high.fahrenheit` to the console, or create an alert calling that, the value is indeed correct. I just cannot seem to set it equal to temp_high.

Comment: Your async operation won't finish before the render.  Can't do it this way.  I don't know react myself, but it probably has a different way to incorporate async operations in a render operation.

Comment: What is an adequate solution? Can I add a waiting point somewhere to ensure that it does finish?

Comment: See [Reactjs async rendering of components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27192621/reactjs-async-rendering-of-components)

Comment: Also, [How to render components after successful async call](https://hashnode.com/post/reactjs-how-to-render-components-only-after-successful-asynchronous-call-ciwvnkjr400sq7t533lvrpdtw).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you want your component's view to update in response to the new data, you need to use setState, to tell React to re-render. React doesn't react (hue) to regular class properties.
2. Async functions shouldn't be called from render. You should instead use [lifecycle hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class), and `componentDidMount` would work best for this situation, to fetch the information once on mount.

With that in mind, you'd end up with something like this:

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    data: null
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // fetch forecast data when the component mounts
    this._getForecast(49306)
  }

  _getForecast(zipcode) {
    const request =
      "http://api.wunderground.com/api/" +
      API_KEY +
      "/forecast/q/" +
      zipcode +
      ".json"

    return axios.get(request).then(response => {
      if (response.status == 200) {
        this.setState({ data: response.data })
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.data === null) {
      // don't render if we haven't received data yet
      // otherwise we'll get an error trying to calculate temp_high
      return
    }

    const temp_high = Number(
      this.state.data.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].high.fahrenheit
    )
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Weather for Belmont, MI</Text>
        <Text>High: {temp_high}</Text>
        <Text />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Using state seemed to fix that. Thank you! React Native is brand new to me — something they don't seem to teach in Uni. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign to a standalone variable (even if it happens to be in the global scope), don't prefix it with `this`. Just

```
temp_high = Number(data.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].high.fahrenheit);
```

`this` resolves to the calling context of the current function you're in.

Answer (score -1):

**This answer is wrong, the arrow allows for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions**)  be carefull with the keyword "this".
It is currently setting the this.temp_high to the _getForecast function. What you might want to do is have

```
 render() {
var self = this;
 this._getForecast(49306).then(data => {
 self.temp_high 
=parseInt(data.forecast.simpleforecast.forecastday[0].high.fahrenheit);
});
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>Weather for Belmont, MI</Text>
    <Text>High: {this.temp_high}</Text>
    <Text></Text>
  </View>
  );
 }
}
```

Comment: A good thought, but the arrow function is what circumvents this c:

Comment: Absolutely right! Will leave it up for educational purposes tho, thanks for catching me